# CSS visited link

Tags: css

[image]I've got a problem with visited CSS link feature.

Here are the requirements:

- links should be black color,
- already visited links, should be a silver color

I've tried several variants but they didn't work.
Here is my last one:

Here is my HTML code:

```css
.heading a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.heading a:visited {
  color: silver;
}
```

```html
<section class="heading tm-content-box">
  <div class="pad">
    <h2> WE ARE...</h2>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="index.html" class="text">Designers</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Consultants</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="text">Strategists</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Engineers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Developers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Architects</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Analysts</a></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It works? Check your browser doesn't use cached (old) css

Comment: Try hard refresh (Ctrl+F5)

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, can you specify exactly in which way it doesn't work? E.G. you get a blue screen of death, the links are green instead etc.

Comment: Mr Lister, all points are silver (I don't know why )

Comment: Maybe you visited all the pages already?